# Trouble drawing graph (again)

Tags: graphs

So, my dear latex editor is making me crazy. He does not want to compile:

```
 \begin{tikzcd}

F  \arrow{r}{\Gamma_F} \arrow{d}{\alpha} & Sh(F)|_B \arrow{d}{\beta_B}\\

G|_B \arrow{r}{=} G|_B

\end{tikzcd}
```

Why?? Thanks for help!

Comment: Please remove the empty lines and also add a second column to the second row, e.g. `G|_B \arrow{r}{=} G|_B & ~\\ `.

Comment: Could you type the concrete code with your changes, as I am a beginner on latex usage??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment. You could drop the empty lines and also make sure that the diagram has a 22 entry. E.g.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
F  \arrow{r}{\Gamma_F} \arrow{d}{\alpha} & Sh(F)|_B \arrow{d}{\beta_B}\\
G|_B \arrow{r}{=} & G|_B \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, no. On the bottom line I need $G_B$ and $G_B$ not this...

Comment: @nikola Then you only need to add a `\&`.